# Formatting microseconds to two decimal places (in fact converting microseconds into tens of microseconds)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am using the following to print out timestamps:

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

However I want to round the microseconds to two decimal places rather than print out to six decimal places. Is there an easier way to achieve this rather than 'unpacking' all the time elements, formatting and rounding the microseconds to 2 decimals, and formatting a new 'print string'?

Comment: Are these `datetime` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decimal_places = 2
ndigits = decimal_places - 6
assert ndigits < 0
d = d.replace(microsecond=round(d.microsecond, ndigits))
print(d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')[:ndigits])
# -> 2014-10-27 11:59:53.87
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to round yourself; use string formatting to format the date without microseconds, then add in the top two digits of the `microsecond` attribute separately:

```
'{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S}.{:02.0f}'.format(dt, dt.microsecond / 10000.0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> '{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S}.{:02.0f}'.format(dt, dt.microsecond / 10000.0)
'27-10-2014 11:56:32.72'
```

Comment: Have done so. Can't help feeling seconds as a float would be a useful addition to datetime().

Answer (score 2):

Based on jfs' answer, I added one more statement as

`replace(microsecond=round(d.microsecond, ndigits))`

may give an error : *ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999*.

i.e. if microsecond is from 995000 to 999999 round(microsecond, ndigits) will give 1000000.

```
d = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time())
decimal_places = 2
ndigits = decimal_places - 6
r = round(d.microsecond, ndigits)
if r > 999999:
    r = 999999
d = d.replace(microsecond=r)
ts = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:ndigits]
```