# DateTime in ISO 8601 + TimeZone and without microseconds

Tags: python, django, pytz, rfc3339

I need date-time string in ISO 8601 without any microseconds.

Like:

```
2015-01-05T11:26:00-03:00
```

I use:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE).localize(datetime.now()).isoformat()
```

But it returns:

```
'2015-01-28T17:49:39.711725-03:00'
```

How to fix that?

Comment: to get the current localized time, use `datetime.now(timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))`. Do not use `.localize(naive_local_time)` -- local time may be ambiguous e.g., during end-of-DST transitions. `now(timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))` always works because it uses `fromutc()` internally while `.localize()` may return a wrong result for ambiguous or non-existent local time.

Comment: related: [Formatting microseconds to two decimal places (in fact converting microseconds into tens of microseconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26586943/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set [`microsecond`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.microsecond) as 0:

```
t = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE).localize(datetime.now()).replace(microsecond=0)
t.isoformat()
```

[`datetime.datetime.replace(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) will return a new `datetime` object with specified attribute modified.